# Confused about the type of the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

> "He will teach me how important I am."

Here '**how important I am**' is the object of the verb teach.
What is the type of the quoted sentence?
Is it assertive or exclamatory??

Answer (score 1):

"He will teach me how important I am" is a complex sentence which can be also termed "assertive".

Here "how important I am" is an object clause.

The rest of the sentence is the main clause.

As about the sentence
 ("How important I am") its type depends on the original punctuation and order of words.

1. "How important I am!" is an exclamation.
2. "How important are you (or: am I)?" is a question.

Comment: +1 but the main clause is not just "He will teach me" but the entire sentence, I believe.